# Proper way to authenticate WebApi backend

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, owin

I am building a WebApi for external consumers. I want to lock it down using Azure AD B2C token authentication. .NET Framework 4.7.2 using Owin middleware.

The workflow (as I understand it) goes like this:

Successful path:

1. GET request on secure endpoint, contains a header with a valid auth token
2. API returns expected result

Invalid/missing token path:

1. GET request on secure endpoint, contains an invalid/missing token in the header(s)
2. API returns 401

This all looks correct from a security point of view, but my poor consumers won't know how to get a new token. Should I be returning something with the 401 to assist in them getting a new token? (i.e. the URL for the Azure AD B2C endpoint) - does this break conventional rules on returning objects with a 401? Am I expecting too much for my consumers to know how to interact with my chosen 3rd-party auth provider?

My question is more about design but would appreciate any technical examples.

Comment: This kind of thing would normally be documented in API documentation.

Comment: +1 to what @juunas said. Wanted to add that generally speaking you're better off being obscure with rejected requests due to Auth as you don't want to provide attackers any additional hints on how to make a successful request.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! So if the API blindly rejects an unauthorised request (sounds good), is it reasonable for the consumers to be aware of the 3rd-party auth provider? e.g. They'll have to know the domain name (login.microsoftonline.com) and how it works, rather than a nicely documented  endpoint on my own system (mydomain.com/gettoken).